# How can i display detailed data from many to many field instead of objects in django rest API , currently im getting only objects of it

Tags: django, django-models, orm, django-rest-framework, django-orm

I'm new to Django,i tryed to list all invoices from my model Invoices and im getting items as only its object, to make the code efficient i need to get the whole data of items in a single query how can i get the details of items along with the data instead of item objects

Here is what i have tryed

> models.py

```
class ItemsInvoice(models.Model):
    invoiceId = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    product_Id = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    item_price = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Invoices(models.Model):
    customer = models.CharField(max_length=10,null=True)
    total_amount = models.CharField(max_length=12,null=True)
    items = models.ManyToManyField(ItemsInvoice,related_name="item_invoice")
```

> views.py

```
class InvoiceView(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = InvoiceSerializers

    def get_queryset(self):
        # queryset = Invoices.objects.prefetch_related('items').all().order_by('-id')
        queryset = Invoices.objects.all().order_by('-id')
        return queryset
```

> serializers.py

```py
class InvoiceSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Invoices
        fields = '__all__'
```

if i run it on my postman, its response will be like this

> API response what i have

```
[
    {
        "id": 69,     
        "customer": "4",
        "total_amount": "25000",
        "items": [
            66,
            67,
            68
        ]
    }
]
```

but actually i want my output like this , ie the item field should list all data inside in it

> API response what i want

```
[
    {
        "id": 69,
        "customer": "4",
        "total_amount": "25000",
        "items": [
            {
                "id": 66,
                "invoiceId": "69",
                "product_Id": "3",
                "item_price": "300",
            },
            {
                "id": 67,
                "invoiceId": "69",
                "product_Id": "4",
                "item_price": "200",
            },
            {
                "id": 68,
                "invoiceId": "69",
                "product_Id": "4",
                "item_price": "200",
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

how can i achieve it by using django-orm or raw query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must define ItemInvoiceSerializer and set many=true.

```
class ItemInvoiceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ItemsInvoice
        fields = '__all__'

class InvoiceSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    items = ItemInvoiceSerializer(many=True) # i changed true to True
    class Meta:
        model = Invoices
        fields = '__all__'
```